# Uninstalling a SQL Server instance using dbatools

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I don't know if this is the right forum for this question, please let me know if it isn't and kindly point me in the right direction. I have just started learning powershell and dbatools.

I am trying to automate uninstalling a SQL Server instance using dbatools. Starting with the following command:

$list = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_product | Select-DbaObject -Property Name
$list.name -cmatch "SQL Server 2019 Database Engine Services".

It returns two entries. My questions:

- There is only one version of SQL Server on the newly built machine, why are two entries returned?
- Is the Engine Service the appropriate service to remove in order to remove all the installed features of the instance at once? $list returns a number of SQL Server 2019 components.

Thank you

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182222/how-to-uninstall-sql-server-instance-silently

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you for your time and response. That link however refers to uninstall from the command line, whereas I am looking to use Powershell/Dbatools. thanks all the same for your help.

Comment: What's the difference? You can call setup.exe from Powershell also. DbaTools doesn't even seem to offer an `Uninstall` cmdlet.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface , thanks again for your time. I found out that the powershell module sqlserverdsc does uninstall, so I am currently trying that out. Much appreciated.